# finding connected component of a given pixel in binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

i want to find a connected component of a given pixel, and then test if another pixel belong to this component in matlab.

```
CC = bwconncomp(BW);
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
...
```

how to loop for all CC, and for each one, and test if a given pixels belong to it!

Comment: Share the code you have tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'd be better off representing the connected components as a labeled image

```
lb = bwlabel( BW );
```

Now, each pixel in `BW` has a label (1..N) while background pixels remains 0.
You can test for pixel `x`,`y` what is its label:

```
 lb( y, x )
```

You can compare the labels of two pixels

```
 lb( y1, x1 ) == lb( y2, x2 )
```